# Are there other "commands" like [edit] for comments?

Tags: support, magic-links

Recently I've been doing some triage reviews and found myself writing a lot of comments doing so. I use `[edit]` quite a lot in my comments to automatically provide a link to edit an answer or question.

So I was wondering if there are any others of those handy commands? I haven't found any resource on it here, but maybe I don't know the right keywords to search for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Many terms have been used to describe these shortcuts, but canonical one that has an associated meta-tag is [meta-tag:magic-links].